# Type-level recursion and PolyKinds

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, polykinds

I'm trying to implement a polymorphic function that essentially traverses a type, accumulating a `Tag` value. I'd like users to be able to do e.g. `rec ((1,2), ('a', 3))`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, PolyKinds, FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
import Data.Proxy

newtype Tag (a :: k) = Tag Int
    deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

-- My users only have to define their own instances of this class...
class Tagged (a :: k) where
  tag :: Tag a

-- ...like these:
instance Tagged Int where
  tag = Tag 1

instance Tagged Char where
  tag = Tag 2

instance Tagged (,) where
  tag = Tag 3


-- While this is a morally "closed" class; implementing recursion over
-- components of types. This is what I'm struggling with:
class Rec (a :: k) where
  rec :: proxy a -> Tag a

instance (Rec ab, Rec c)=> Rec (ab c) where
  rec _ = let Tag ab = rec Proxy :: Tag ab
              Tag c = rec Proxy :: Tag c
           in Tag (ab * c)

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Tagged a=> Rec a where
  rec _ = tag :: Tag a
```

I've fiddled with this in various ways, and in the current incarnation get the error (for both `ab` and `c`, in the first instance):

```
    • Could not deduce (Tagged ab) arising from a use of ‘rec’
      from the context: (Rec ab, Rec c)
        bound by the instance declaration at flook.hs:26:10-37
    • In the expression: rec Proxy :: Tag ab
      In a pattern binding: Tag ab = rec Proxy :: Tag ab
      In the expression:
        let
          Tag ab = rec Proxy :: Tag ab
          Tag c = rec Proxy :: Tag c
        in Tag (ab * c)
   |
27 |   rec _ = let Tag ab = rec Proxy :: Tag ab
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm a little surprised at this error since it seems to indicate the second base case instance was selected a priori in the body of the first instance.

Is there a way to get this to work, or a better approach?

Comment: Why do you use a proxy for one class and not the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should skip having two classes. Just one suffices.

The drawback is that your users won't be able to write instances corresponding to `instance Tagged (Maybe Int)` in your design which do something special for compound types... but they already couldn't really use those, since the application instance for `Rec` would always overlap it anyway.

So, without further ado:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Tagged

class Rec a where rec :: Tagged a Int

-- it is still possible for users to define their own instances for base types
instance Rec Int  where rec = 1
instance Rec Char where rec = 2
instance Rec (,)  where rec = 3

instance (Rec ab, Rec c) => Rec (ab c) where
  rec = retag (rec :: Tagged ab Int) * retag (rec :: Tagged c Int)
```

In ghci:

```
> rec :: Tagged ((Int, Int), Char) Int
Tagged 18
```

Comment: Oh, yeah this is much better, thanks. It hadn't occurred to me that I wouldn't actually need overlapping instances with this approach as well